# How do I selectively disable the GDBus "PropertiesChanged" signal?

Tags: gdbus

I am building an [MPRIS D-Bus Interface](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/index.html) for an application in C using GDBus facilities generated automagically using the gdbus-codegen tool.

When a property is altered, a "PropertiesChanged" signal is automatically generated, which is fine most of the time, but in the MPRIS specification, it states that when the 'Position' property changes, [the "PropertiesChanged" signal should not be emitted](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/Player_Interface.html#Property:Position).

Is there any nice way to prevent the signal being sent?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible, due to a [missing feature in GLib](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=674913). Once that feature is implemented, you should be able to annotate the `Position` property with `org.freedesktop.DBus.Property.EmitsChangedSignal` to cause `gdbus-codegen` to not emit signals for it.

This would use the following introspection XML, for example:

```
<property name="Position" type="x" access="read">
  <annotation name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Property.EmitsChangedSignal" value="false"/>
</property>
```

If you want to help out on the GLib bug, that would be appreciated (at the least, subscribe to it to hear when it’s fixed). I will try and find time to review the patch soon, but can make no guarantees.

Comment: Many thanks -- I will do that. (The app in question is Shairport Sync.)